# When should muslims give Zakat on money?

Tags: practical-islam, zakat

**Updated:**

When should muslims give Zakat? Is it between a period or can everyone choose when to give?

Zakat is one of the pillars of Islam. I don't mean any other charity or even Udhia.

Comment: helpful [Should 14 year old pay Zakat on benefit money that is being saved?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18189/should-14-year-old-pay-zakat-on-benefit-money-that-is-being-saved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first thanks for searching about that. May Allah guide you to the best for you and for all Muslims in shaa Allah.

You might give Zakat any time if you are able to do that. But Zakat as Allah ordered us have many kinds:

1. If you have lands you should give Zakat when you harvest.
2. If you have money over the nisab, you should give Zakat from it if the money stays with you whole year.
3. We should give Zakat el-fiter, breakfast zakat on Eid el-fiter, before the Eid prayer. It's preferable to give Zakat el-fiter 2 days before Eid.

And Allah and his prophet know the best.