# Should 14 year old pay Zakat on benefit money that is being saved?

Tags: zakat, age

My little brother is diabetic and gets benefit money from the government every year that my parents have held for him until he is 18. This money is being saved with the intention it may go towards improving his quality of life should something in future help with his diabetes.

We need to know if we should be paying Zakat on this money every year? He is 14 years old and the money is held on his own bank account that my parents transfer to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do children below the age of puberty have to pay zakat?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9734/do-children-below-the-age-of-puberty-have-to-pay-zakat)

Comment: @السید____علی, I don't think it is a duplicate, as the question focuses on whether Zakat should be paid if that certain amount of money is to improve someones health and to stop them from getting ill and/or dying _prematurely_. Although I may be wrong :)

Comment: One of the problems with Islam in modern Weatern democracies is that there is no established *ulema* that one can seek rulings on situations specific and particular to them. One could argue, that given *Zakat*, being a means of paying alms to the poor or needy, that welfare payments are a form of *Zakat*.

Answer (score 1):

Zakat must be paid by anyone having wealth more than nisab amount (85 grams of gold or 595 grams of silver).

> It does not matter whether the owner of the money is below the age of
>   puberty or mentally disabled, zakat must be paid.

References, if you need:

http://www.amjaonline.org/fatwa-76302/info

https://islamqa.info/en/75307

Comment: This is the source of the ruling but it doesn't show how the ruling applies in a democratic welfare state.

Answer (score 0):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

As far as I know, it is not mandatory for the people who are under the age of puberty (Bolugh). Actually, I reckon your question can be surveyed from two aspects. Initially, does this issue need to pay Zakat? (That, to be honest, I am not sure about it as a mandatory issue to pay Zakat.)

On the other hands, apparently if he is under the age puberty, it is not mandatory to pay Zakat. But in the case that it be Mandatory to pay Zakat (in the mentioned matter), then I reckon it ought to be calculate after the age of puberty, not before the puberty. God willing you obtain the certain answer of this question.